# Matplotlib line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, line-plot

I am trying to plot a simple line graph using matplotlib and for some reason, matlpotlib is plotting the data incorrectly.

Here are examples of the data I am trying to plot:

[image: CSV Data]

[image: Pandas Plot (What the graph should look like)]

[image: Matplotlib Graph]

The code that I have constructed is rather basic as the following:

```
fh = df['Datetime']
temp = df['tmp']
dew = df['dpt']
winds = df['wsp']

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.plot(fh,df['tmp'],marker='o')
ax.set_ylabel('MOS Forecasted Temperature (degF)')

plt.xticks(rotation='90')

plt.legend()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the matplotlib graph would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df = df.sort_values('Datetime')` at the very top should fix this.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!